# Separating Numbers in the Same Input And Finding the Minimum; PY

Tags: python

What I need to do is take numbers from a given input, separate each number into single digits, and add them together so if the input is 123 it'll separate into 1, 2, 3 and then add them together and print 6

I'm guessing I need to add the numbers to a list and split it but I'm not sure how
So far I've tried:

```
def small(x):
    L = []
    y = x.split(',')
    mini = 10000000000000000000000000
    for i in y:
        var1 = int(i)
        var2 = int(var1)
        L.append(var2)
    for i in L:
        if i < mini:
            mini = i
    return mini

def total(x):
    L = []
    t = 0
    y = x.split(',')
    va1 = ''
    for i in y:
        var1 = int(i)
        var2 = int(var1)
        L.append(var2)
    for i in L:
        t = t + i
    return t
def main():
x = input(">>")
print(small(x))

print(total(x))

main()
```

but this only prints out

```
>>1,3,5,6
1
15
```

Comment: I added in the code for what I have so far and tried calling small(x) in the main() function but I'm really confused

Comment: Could you be more specify? puts a example of you output

Comment: We really need an [MCVE] to be able to help you here.  Your code is a start, of course, but examples of the inputs and the expected output would also be very helpful.

Comment: How do you infer your output is wrong? This works for me: `print sum([int(x) for x in list('1356')]), min(list('1356'))` -> `15, 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inputs from @Rad I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
x = input("enter a number: ")
myList = [int(i) for i in str(x)]
print myList

#calculate sum
print "Sum is: "+ str(sum(myList))

#finding minimum
print "Minimum: " + str(min(myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with that code :

```
y = str(x)
s = 0
for nb in y :
    print nb
    s = s + int(nb)
    print s
```